# passing differnt color variables to the same class

Tags: css

I have a page that has several elements that use the the same css class.  I would like to have a different background color for each element without making my css file way large.  Is there a way to do something in my html like class="xyz (something)" and in the css file have background-color: (something);?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to replicate all properties for all classes

```
.classnameforall{
    /*your css goes here. does not matter if it has background-color, it will be the default one if you do not use other classes*/
}
.redbg{background-color:red;}
.greenbg{background-color:green;}
.some-otherbg{background-color:#df4533;}
```

and use it like you asked

```
class="classnameforall redbg"
```

or

```
class="classnameforall greenbg"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is don't specify background-color in css file. But for each element use inline style with only property being background-color and specify required class which has all other styling property.

Thus all elements will have different background color, but other styles will remain same for them.

```
.classname{
  all other styles except background-color;


}

<element class="classname" style="background-color:red" >
```

**JS FIDDLE DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/sXF5T/

Comment: Inline CSS is not a good idea -- if you are going to do something in your HTMl then why not put a i.e red-color

Answer (score 0):

Try with the pseudo selector nth-child(an + b)

```
p:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  background: red;
}
p:nth-child(2n + 2) {
  background: blue;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gomflo/gtpsX/